# AWS - Route53 how to point static IP of lightsail instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have purchased a domain (expressXXXX.it) in Route53.
After this, I have created a lightsail instance in AWS, and assigned a static ip address to it.

In "hosted zones", i configured as follow, adding only A and CNAME records:

[image]

where 99.xxx.xx.x4 is my static ip address.

The url [www.expressxxxxxxx.it](http://www.expressxxxxxxx.it) does not point to my static ip address.
if i ping expressxxxx.it, i can see that it points to 42.525.xxx.xxxx instead of my static ip address 99.xx.xx.xx.

I waited for several hours, but it doesn't work at all.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Does performing a DIG command on your domain show the record?

Comment: hi @ChrisWilliams, yes it shows the record

Comment: What type of error are you seeing?

Comment: The url www.expressxxxxxxx.it does not point to my static ip address

Comment: Does DNS resolution work correctly for the version _without_ `www`?

Comment: Are name servers properly configured? You can check it trough who is lookup portal